# Analyzing Iterative Algorithms : basic operations, number of basic operations executed and class O(...) algorithms belongs to?

Tags: algorithm, math

Can someone please explain to me clearly how to answer this questions i've been straggling to understand it ?

The Question says:

**Let X and Y be two arrays of n numbers. The Algorithms below calculate various expressions on the arrays. Analyze the time complexity of each algorithm and find :**

**i) What are the algorithm's basic operations ?**

**ii) How many times  are the basic operations executed ?**

**iii) what is the class O(..) the algorithm belongs to ?**

```
X+Y

ALGORITHM addArrays(X[0..n-1],Y[0..n-1)

//Input: Two arrays X and Y of n numbers

//Output: Array S= X +Y

For i <--0 to n-1 do

           S[i] <-- X[u] + Y[i]
Output S[0 . . n-1]
```

Comment: Have you missed some courses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ) Adds the two input arrays and returns the sum array (`S`). That's the line inside the loop that adds each input array's entry on each iteration of the loop.

ii) n times as you only call upon the addition operation n times..

iii) O(n) because you're only going through n elements in total (2n accesses but that's `O(n)`).

Comment: How does this work ? can you explain it to me please.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Is that clear enough now or do you not understand why 2n is O(n)?

Comment: for i) the basic operation that is used to calculate the algorithm is addition right ? because S= X + Y ii) the basic operations executed n times because the repeat of the addition operations. iii) how did you get 2n ?

Comment: It's 2n array accesses (n for each array, because you're accessing each array n times). But 2n falls in the O(n) category.